How to get the build status of UpStream build
I am using declarative pipeline syntax in jenkinsfile and I have 3 jobs executed in order JobA->JobB->JobC 
JobB will be triggered on successful execution of JobA.and JobC will be triggered on all execution of JobB.
I would Like to capture the status of JobB and to use it in further stages of JobC.
How can I get the upstream job result
currentBuild.buildCauses does not give the status of upstream Job and currentBuild.upstreamBuilds also does not print anything use full. it prints `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper@1bc1b0b
9`
Edit:
I am not triggering downstream job from upstream like build job:jobname. I am monitoring upstream job using build trigger in downstream job

How do you trigger your downstream job?


Save the result of the JobB into a variable:

def jobB = build job: 'JobB', propagate: false, wait: true
def jobBResult = jobB.result


Define a parameter in JobC:

pipeline {
    parameters { string(name: 'jobBResult', defaultValue: '', description: '') }
    ...
}


Pass the result as a parameter to JobC:

build job: 'JobC', propagate: true, wait: true, parameters: [string(name: 'jobBResult', value: jobBResult)]


I have updated the question . Can you help with that
